# Is it possible to "refresh" a parent control to "update/refresh" child control margins?

Tags: c#, winforms

I placed two `GroupBox` controls next to each other (left and right) separated by their `Margin` value in designer. Then, when the program runs, I resize the left `GroupBox`'s `Width` and it overlaps into the second `GroupBox`.

Is it possible to call some sort of refresh on the parent control to re-draw all children with the correct `Margins`? I tried `Invalidate` on the parent but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Can You put code on jsFidle?

Comment: @MarkHall It's too late for me. I was though it is question about html :)

Comment: How do you resize the left GroupBox's Width? Programatically?

Comment: @GianAcuna Yes, `groupBox1.Width = 200;` is just a dummy, larger value (the real value will depend on the label of the groupbox). Then I would like the `GroupBox` to the right of it to then shift by 200 also (to maintain the `Margin` value).

Answer (score 0):

try make left GroupBox's Dock=Left  and right GroupBox's Dock=Fill ,children also use Dock property ,mybe you can make it
it works with framework4 ,id didn't try other version

also you can add two GroupBoxs into one Panel fro your spacel layout

Answer (score 0):

unless you specifically chose a flowlayoutpanel or something similar, your button are fixed to their location unless moved. No amount of re-layout is going to fix that.

I recommend you go back to the designer, add a flowlayoutpanel and move your buttons onto that panel.